# No gui after uninstalling gtk2.0 in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk

I have ubuntu 16.10 version installed. I uninstalled gtk using sudo apt-get remove --purge gtk2.0. After rebooting, my whole gui is not loading, no login screen also. I can access other terminals using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>. How can i get my gui interface back?. Anyhelp is appreciated.thanks.

Comment: When you remove a package, you have to watch what other packages get removed as a result. GTK+ 2 is still a widely used package in a lot of places, so I'm not surprised things stopped working, and you might not be able to remove it for a long time. GTK+ 3 is not compatible with GTK+ 2, so you have to have both versions installed if you want to use apps that are written for both versions. What desktop environment do you use?

Comment: Default gnome environment

Comment: Also I see you tried removing GTK+ 2 because of your other question. Not only would that not have helped, because the problem was not with GTK+ at all, but GTK+ 2 is not the version of GTK+ you were developing with! You should be very careful next time you try to fix a problem by uninstalling and reinstalling, which is usually NOT the fix to begin with.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 5):

You might probably want to try this:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^`

This should install all the packages of standard Ubuntu Desktop that you've removed.

Alternatively, you can check the logs of apt `/var/log/apt/history.log` and install back the packages that got removed.